# Spring Boot Custom Authorization Header request not going through at all

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have a Spring Boot application and I am sending a request to it using PostMan. It is using Spring Security along with JWT for authentication. I'm trying to get authorization to work but am running into issues. Spring is able to login the user and return a token fine. But when I put the token in the header it's not working at all. I get no response from the server. When the token is removed, it works fine. Right now all requests should be able to go through regardless of being logged in or not.

My Spring Web Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }
}
```

The REST path I'm trying to access:

```
@RestController("threadService")
@RequestMapping("/api/thread")
public class ThreadService {
    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ThreadDetails> getThreadList() {
        logger.info("getThreadList");
        return threadDao.getThreadList();
    }
}
```

The failed GET request I'm issuing after I have logged in and gotten a token:

```
GET /api/thread/list HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization : Bearer (JWT token here)
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 69565839-4806-b4f6-9a03-11382a80c7da
```

The above request works fine when there is no Authorization in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is exactly the problem I was facing.
When I want to communicate with the restservice exposed by spring boot application, the "Authorization" is not set. I followed the steps which are required to communicate but the value wont be passes through header.

The solution I found, the "common-codec" library was missing. Once I add the dependency in my web application, it start sending the "Authorization" in header to my spring boot application.
Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: Ok, nice, in your case, but how about when you do the request on Postman and everything works well but when you do using, let's say Axios (in React), the Authorization header never reaches the server side on the request header?

Comment: Could you solve it? having the same issue here